# Toggle View with Jquery and hide Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have searched a lot and my some own tries aswell.

I want to achieve that a (in this case Wordpress Excerpt is shown) as soon as you click on the readmore the Excerpt disappears and the full post drops down smoothly.

So far this is my code

```
<div class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link trigger" href="#"><i class="fa 
 fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>  <a class="close trigger" 
 href="#"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <div class="excerpt">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>    
  </div>
  <div id="<?php echo the_ID(); ?>" class="dropdown-container" 
  style="display: none;">
  <div class="full-content">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php

if( have_rows('downloads') ):
       echo '<h4>Weiter Informationen zum Download:</h4>';
       echo '<ul class="fa-ul">';
       while ( have_rows('downloads') ) : the_row(); ?>


    <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-arrow-down"></i><a href="<?php 
   the_sub_field('file'); ?>" title="<?php the_sub_field('title'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></a></li>
   <?php
endwhile;

   else :

   // no rows found

   endif;

     ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

adding I used the Code from http://jsfiddle.net/NFTFw/29/ to have only one post opened at a time, now I needed to hide the extract and make a close button, so with my limited jQuery capabilities I added this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("close").hide();
  $('div.dropdown').each(function() {
    var $dropdown = $(this);

    $("a.dropdown-link", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $div = $("div.dropdown-container", $dropdown);
      $div.toggle();
      $("div.dropdown-container").not($div).hide();
      $("a.dropdown-link").hide();
      $(".excerpt").hide();
      $(".close").show();
      return false;
    });

  });

  $('html').click(function() {
    $("div.dropdown-container").hide();
  });

});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".close", $hide).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $div = $("div.dropdown-container", $hide);
    $div.toggle();
    $("div.dropdown-container").not($div).show();
    $("a.dropdown-link").show();
    $(".excerpt").show();
    $(".close").hide();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Not it not only hide one excerpt but all, doesn't show me the more (mehr lesen) button anymore but just the close button and no content at all.

Can someone spot the issue (or issues) and maybe explain what I did wrong?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: i think its helpful for your requirements [https://codepen.io/maxds/pen/jgeoA](https://codepen.io/maxds/pen/jgeoA)

Comment: Doesn't help since it should work as in the jsfiddle, not showing two Posts and once and I am required to use the excerpt() and content() function of Wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.dropdown').each(function() {
var $dropdown = $(this);
var $div = $dropdown.find(".dropdown-container");
var $excerpt = $dropdown.find(".excerpt");

$dropdown.find('.dropdown-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".dropdown-container").not($div).hide();
    $(".excerpt").not($excerpt).show();
    $div.toggle();
    $excerpt.toggle();
    $dropdown.find(".dropdown-link .fa").toggleClass("fa-caret-down").toggleClass("fa-times");
    return false;
});
});

$('html').click(function(){
 $(".dropdown-container").hide();
 $(".excerpt").show();
 $(".dropdown .dropdown-link .fa").removeClass("fa-times").addClass("fa-caret-down");
 });
 });
```